# Angular 2 beta typings in Visual Studio (ASP.NET 4)

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

In the alpha versions of Angular 2.0 I worked with the files from DefinitelyTyped to use typings for TypeScript in Visual Studio. This was simple by just adding the d.ts files to the project. In the current beta stage this seems to be different since DefinitelyTyped no longer provides this file and they have been moved to the angular repo directly.

Problem is that I don't know which file to include to the project in the first place, including all of them throws tons of errors while compiling.

My setup is a DNN website with my VS project residing in the DesktopModules folder, meaning that my project is not the root of the website. I use SystemJS to load components from various locations within this site.

Is there a simple way to include one d.ts file or compose it so that TypeScript can compile correctly?

**EDIT - To explain it more detailed:**

When I was using import statement`import * as ng from 'angular2/angular2'` in the alpha, the 'angular2/angular2' (path and JS file) was resolved by SystemJS and Visual Studio knew about it because of the definition file that was declaring a module. How do I achieve that Visual Studio will know about that again? I tried many hours without success, except using the old Alpha stage .d.ts file and changing it slightly to declare it as `angular2/core`.

How can this problem be resolved **without** using the new project system of ASP.NET 5?

Comment: are you looking for `intellisense and hint for code` checking for angular2 in VS code ?

Comment: Indeed, otherwise Visual Studio will not compile the project.

Answer (score 1):

Since TypeScript has introduced the "exclude" section in tsconfig.json the preferable way of setting up project is instead of manually including every file that is a part of your project using "files" section of tsconfig, you exclude unwanted ones and everything else will be automatically considered part of your project.

Angular2 comes with typings as its part. You no longer need to manually add them via tsd/typings. Your IDE should be able to automatically resolve them.

Make sure though that you will exclude at least "node_modules" folder in tsconfig.json so compiler will not try to compile its contents and you will not end up with tons of "duplicate identifier" errors.

For more details you can follow sample walkthrough specifically for VS: [Starting Angular 2 in ASP.NET 5 with TypeScript using Visual Studio 2015](http://www.mithunvp.com/angular-2-in-asp-net-5-typescript-visual-studio-2015/)

Comment: This tutorial describes the VS setup for ASP.NET 5, I have to use the old project management for VS. Until alpha 41 it was simple: setup SystemJS, place the .d.ts file for Angular 2 somewhere in the project and use `import * as ng from 'angular2/angular2'` in your TypeScript file. Now none of this works anymore. You can still use the Alpha 39 version of the typings but this is not the way it should be I think.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a very simple solution. I can accept this workaround because it is only needed at development time.

First of all, in order to make all the magic work you have to use the GitHub source code of DNN and include your projects to the solution.

For Visual Studio to find the typings I just copied the angular2 folder from my JSPM location to the root of the website (rxjs is needed in addition). In this case the statement `import * as ng from 'angular2/core'` will let Visual Studio search in the root of the website for a folder called `angular2` and a file named `core`. By doing this, everything is compiling fine, all errors are gone and IntelliSense is working again.

This is no problem at runtime because all script files are loaded through SystemJS from the location where your JSPM packages reside (in other words those newly copied folders are not needed, it's just for VS to find the typings).

I also wanna mention that this no problem with Angular itself, TypeScript just does not know anything about JSPM and therefore can not find the right location to load the typings from. There is a discussion on the TypeScript repo on GitHub which can give you more details on that. In future versions there could be a way to tell TypeScript some paths to lookup, or maybe even an integration of JSPM and TypeScript.

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6012

Answer (score -1):

I have found that the real important include in VS is the typescript.d.ts file. This is in the node-modules\typescript\lib folder. I also include the js files in the index.html, but that is only to get rid of the red squigles.